# Selecting paragraph tagged with itemprop=recipeInstructions using jsoup on android

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I've tried my query in http://try.jsoup.org/ and it works fine.  However, when I try it on android (4.2.2) it is returning a zero sized array.

The query I want is [itemprop=recipeInstructions].

The website I'm testing on is http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/recipes/real-meatballs-and-spaghetti-674.html

My android code looks like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/recipes/real-meatballs-and-spaghetti-674.html").get();
Elements recipe = doc.select("[itemprop=recipeInstructions]"); 
// recipe is a zero sized array :(
```

I'm linking against jsoup-1.7.3.jar

My android code works fine on the website http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/broccoli-and-bow-ties-recipe.html so I suspect it's a bug in the html or how jsoup parses the html of the first site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the "User Agent".

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/4.0").get();
```

Because, the server may return to different page according to different browser identification.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
Elements recipe = doc.select("p[itemprop = recipeInstructions]");
```

Comment: That works on the try.jsoup site, but not on android again :-(

Comment: Did you execute your task into an asyncTask ? It's maybe the reason of the null value of your array.

Comment: Yup, it's running inside an AsyncTask (if you try to run it from the main thread I think you get an exception).